# Plugins are updated succesfully but still are not displayed as updated

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to update some plugins which are required to be updated, I succesfully update them but when I return to plugins list, they are still displayed as not updated.

My situation is in next 2 screenshoots.
Theme is ToTe (premium)

[Successfully updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyZ62.png) AND 
[Still not displaying after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLxM4.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to talk to your theme developer to provide latest version of these plugins or if you have updation for theme also update that first after that update plugins.
because you got these plugins with theme and theme.
so talk to theme developer to provide latest version plugins
hope this helps you